# CSS labels above the input fields in a table

Tags: html, css

im trying to change the design of my table. Atm i have this:
[image]

I would like to get something like this:

[image]

I want to get the label above the input box, so that i looks like the example. 
This is my code:

```
<table class="table">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Title:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="title">
            </td>
            <td>Position: </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="position">
            </td>
            <td>Input Type:</td>
            <td>
                <select id="input">
                    <option value="1">Drop-down</option>
                    <option value="2">Radio Buttons</option>
                    <option value="3">Checkbox</option>
                    <option value="4">Multiple Select</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>Required?</td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="required">
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Cheers and happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Just use the line break element [`<br>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br)

```html
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Title: <br>
        <input type="text" id="title">
      </td>
      <td>Position: <br>
        <input type="text" id="position">
      </td>
      <td>Input Type: <br>
        <select id="input">
          <option value="1">Drop-down</option>
          <option value="2">Radio Buttons</option>
          <option value="3">Checkbox</option>
          <option value="4">Multiple Select</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>Required? <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="required">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add another row above !

```html
<table class="table">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>Title:</td>
        <td>Position: </td>
        <td>Input Type:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="title">
            </td>
            
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="position">
            </td>
            
            <td>
                <select id="input">
                    <option value="1">Drop-down</option>
                    <option value="2">Radio Buttons</option>
                    <option value="3">Checkbox</option>
                    <option value="4">Multiple Select</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="required"> Required ?
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: @Morgs : Thanks for the edit. I alos started with a column for `Required`, but the user seems to want the text "Required" next to the checkbox ...

Answer (score 0):

don't worry friend

simple use `<br>` tag

**like this**

```
<div class="col_3">
<label>Title</label></br>
<input type="text"/>
</div>
<div class="col_3">
<label>Title</label></br>
<input type="text"/>
</div>
<div class="col_3">
<label>Title</label></br>
<input type="text"/>
</div>

<style>

.col_3{
width:31.33%;
float:left;
}
.col_3 label{
wisth:100%;
}
.col_3 input{
width:100%;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to tell you, that nobody uses table these days for this kind of stuff. Make a switch to `div`s for the better.

Using `<br>` is okay, but you can make those `label` elements block-level too, to automatically acquire the available width and push the `input` next to them below in the display order.

You may use `div` inside the form to create a columnar fashion; provide a `width`, float them left, add some padding for separation and white-space, and you are done!

You may take advantage of [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) as well, to make it more flexible.

Here is some code for example, see it yourself.

```css
/* Tweaking the box */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

/* Avoid using `<br`, push the label to block-level */
.label-block {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

/* Column-settings for the form */
.job-form-col {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-width: 0 0 1px;
}

.job-form-col:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.job-form-col:last-child {
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}

/* Form column rendering settings for different screen sizes */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .job-form-col {
    float: left;
    border-width: 0 1px 0 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .job-form-col {
    width: 25%;
    padding: 1.25em;
  }
  
  .job-form-col:nth-child(4n) {
    border-width: 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) and (min-width: 768px) {
  .job-form-col {
    width: 50%;
    padding: .75em;
  }
  
  .job-form-col:nth-child(2n) {
    border-width: 0;
  }

}
```

```html
<form action="" class="job-form">

  <div class="job-form-col">

    <label class="label-block" for="title">Option Title</label>
    <input type="text" id="title">

  </div>
  <!-- .job-form-col -->

  <div class="job-form-col">

    <label class="label-block" for="position">Position</label>
    <input type="text" id="position">

  </div>
  <!-- .job-form-col -->

  <div class="job-form-col">

    <label class="label-block" for="drop-down">Drop-down</label>
    <select name="" id="drop-down">
      <option value="">Lorem.</option>
      <option value="">Alias.</option>
      <option value="">Odit!</option>
      <option value="">Totam!</option>
      <option value="">Numquam.</option>
    </select>
    <!-- #drop-down -->

  </div>
  <!-- .job-form-col -->

  <div class="job-form-col">

    <input type="checkbox" id="required">
    <label for="required">Required?</label>

  </div>
  <!-- .job-form-col -->

</form>
<!-- .job-form -->
```

Start using `<div>` for `<table>` when it comes to layout things on web. Happy learning!

Comment: Thanks, Ill have a look at that!